# Android Studio 3.1.3 Error while cloning project from GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio, github

When I clone any project from GitHub, the design view in the layout editor stops working. The sdk version picker and the device picker on the top bar show null or no value.

Comment: a screenshot would be nice as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common error which I too have faced while cloning projects from GitHub.
Here's a fix -

[image]

Make sure you have at least 1 SDK API Level fully installed. If not, check it from the list below and download it first.

Else, if you already have an Android SDK location, Click on the 'edit' field near the Android Sdk Location. Now, leave everything as is and just click next/yes/accept to all prompts.

You should have the SDK picker and device picker working now.